# In the Movie Looper, how does this happen?

Tags: looper

How is Seth's older self able to escape if his legs have been cut off? Shouldn't the timeline change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doesn't the end of Looper create a time paradox?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24366/doesnt-the-end-of-looper-create-a-time-paradox) since this question/answer applies to pretty much every time-travel-snafu in the film.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work that way.  Anything you do to a looper's younger self does affect the looper's older self, *but not until you do it*.

No, it doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  But it is what it is.  And at the end of the day, the time travel only exists to support the needs of the plot.  Best not to worry about it, or in other words,  ["Don't think so much."](https://www.npr.org/2012/09/27/161881523/looper-time-travel-nonsense-winningly-played)

Comment: So he runs with the *legs of plot convenience* 

Comment: There is no plot hole, I explained the rules of time travelling here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/24370/4698.